# Load different language from class CI_Controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing multilingual  website. 
I wrote following code in CI_Controller class file so that I don't have to load language to each controller file.

```
$this->lang->load('english');
```

Problem is when I have to change other language for example: let's say spanish.

```
$this->lang->load('spanish');
```

How to I load between these two language when I choose Language >  English / Spanish from menu option?

Comment: My suggestion is set lang type(english/spanish) in session. then load the lang accordingly in base controller constructor.

Comment: How do I define session in CI_Controller class file?

Answer (score 1):

**Checking and Loading**

place this code in controller `constructor`

```
 $this->load->library('session');
 $lang= $this->session->userdata('language');

if($lang != ''){
    switch($lang){
        case    'en'    :   
            $this->lang->load('english', 'english');
            break;
        case    'sp'    :   
            $this->lang->load('spanish', 'spanish');
            break;
    }
}
```

**Setting lang**

place this code where you setting the `lang`

```
$this->session->set_userdata('language', '<set english or spanish>')
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object in FILE PATH\system\core\Controller.php on line 53

I want to set language on system/core/contoller.php file ie CI_Controller class.
So that I don't have to use it in all the controller files.

Comment: just add `$this->load-?library('session');` at top or add `session` in lirararies array at `config/autoload.php`

Answer (score 1):

if you have any application installed built in codeigniter or u are making 1 and u wanna add some language pack just follow these steps:
 1: Add language files in folder application/language/arabic (i add arabic lang in stock manager advance built in codeigniter) 
2: go to the file named setting.php in application/modules/settings/views/setting.php here u find the array

```
<?php /*

 $lang = array (
  'english' => 'English',

  'arabic' => 'Arabic',  // i add this here

  'spanish' => 'Español'
```

now save and run the application its worked fine