# How to access the URI in autoload.php file

Tags: codeigniter

How to access the file name and function name present in the URL in autoload.php file of codeigniter.

I can access the file name but how to access the function name ?

Only the file name is stored in the session?

Comment: Why do you need method in `autoload.php` ?

Comment: To load the language files according to the functions of perticular file called

Comment: Better to use query params for language change. If it is specific to few pages.

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430734/load-different-language-from-class-ci-controller-in-codeigniter/15469874

Comment: Actually I have some language files on application/language/english folder. When the user made request to particular page the language files required for that page are loaded... By using the session variable I can access the file name from URL ,But how to access the Function name from the URL? Because I need to load the language files according to the function name...

Comment: If possible pass the language param in `url` for that specific pages. load the appropriate `language` accordingly with that param.